# How to retrieve last Record inserted in database which is in X,Y,Z STATE using spring data mongodb?

Tags: java, spring-data-mongodb

**Problem**

How to retrieve last Record inserted in database which is in X,Y,Z STATE using spring data mongodb.

**Below is my schema -**

```
class Order1{

private DateTime createdAt;//it store last record inserted

private STATE state;

}

enum STATE

{

X,

Y,

Z

}
```

**Solution I Implemented:**

I implemented this method in repository and it doesn't work.

```
Order1 findTopByOrderByCreatedAtDescAndOrderStatusIn(List<STATE> items);
```

> Can anyone guide me how can i apply query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to create a new method

```
findTopbyOrderStatusIn(List<STATE> items, Sort sort)
```

and when calling the method create the sort in this way 
 Sort.by(new Order(DESC, "createdAt") this is going to allow you pass a different type of sort.